# Send values from select in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to send ID of selected option to my parent component. Also, when the value of my dropdown changes I want to toggle some of my dropdowns to stop being disabled.

This is my custom dropdown component:

```
<template>
 <select
   @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
   v-bind="$attrs"
   @change="change"
 >
   <option :value="null" disabled selected>
     {{ placeholder }}
   </option>
   <option v-for="option in options" :key="option.id" :value="option">
     {{ option.model }}
   </option>
 </select>
</template>
```

The problem is that I should send the ID of my option (option.componentable_id), but if I handle value change here then my logic in parent component won't work.

Currently, my parent component has this:

```
     <Dropdown
      placeholder="Odaberi matičnu ploču"
      :options="motherboards"
      hardcoded-value="First option"
      class="pc-builder-sixth-background"
      :change="setIsMotherboardChosen"
    />
```

Relevant to that, I have 2 dropdowns that are being enabled or disabled depending on this state:

```
    <Dropdown
      placeholder="Odaberi RAM memoriju"
      :options="rams"
      hardcoded-value="First option"
      class="pc-builder-fourth-drodpown"
      :disabled="!isMotherboardChosen"
    />
```

Function to set my value is here:

```
function setIsMotherboardChosen() {
  isMotherboardChosen.value = !isMotherboardChosen.value;
  console.log(isMotherboardChosen.value);
}
```

I know currently the code isn't so clean, but I just want to send my id and toggle value in the same time. I tried different types of binds etc. but the problem is that I have to do 2 things in different files so I'm struggling. I have managed to make disabling logic, but I don't know how to connect it with my ID API logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not listening for any events in the parent.
To listen to the input event you should use `@input`, and the method you want to call when the event is captured:

```
<Dropdown @input="setIsMotherboardChosen"
```

Even better though would be to use [v-model](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html) as this is the exact situation that it's meant for (two-way binding)

**Parent**

```js
const motherboardOption = ref(null)
```

```html
<template>
  <Dropdown v-model="motherboardOption" />
</template>
```

**Child**

```js
import { reactive, computed } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps(['modelValue'])
const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])

const value = computed({
  get() {
    return props.modelValue
  },
  set(value) {
    emit('update:modelValue', value)
  }
})
```

```html
<select v-model="value">
  <option :value="null" disabled selected>
    placeholder
  </option>
  <option v-for="option in options" :key="option.id" :value="option">
    {{ option.model }}
  </option>
</select>
```

This way, whenever a dropdown option is selected, `motherboardOption` in the parent will have that value immediately assigned to it, meaning the option id will be accessible as `motherboardOption.id`, and you can still use this value when setting your `:disabled` props:

```html
<Dropdown :disabled="!motherboardOption" />
```

[Vue Playground example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 0):

At this point, it would be better and easier to use `v-mount` attribute and bind it to a ref. It should work the same for your component

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

// ref that will store our selected value
const message = ref('')
</script>

<template>
  <p>Message is: {{ message }}</p>
   <!-- `v-model`is used to bind selection to `message` ref -->
  <input v-model="message" placeholder="input" />
</template>
```

You can find more about handling forms in the [vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).